# Need to copy specific XML node from one doc to another

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have two XML files (that have a number of common nodes) that look a bit like these:

```
DESTINATION FILE: ('destination.xml')
<items>
    <item>
         <title>Item A</title>
         <description>This is the description for Item A</description>
         <id>1001</id>
    </item>
    <item>
         <title>Item B</title>
         <description>This is the description for Item B</description>
         <id>1002</id>
    </item>
    <item>
         <title>Item D</title>
         <description>This is the description for Item D</description>
         <id>1004</id>
    </item>
```

and

```
SOURCE FILE: ('source.xml')
<items>
    <item>
         <title>Item A</title>
         <description>This is the description for Item A</description>
         <id>1001</id>
    </item>
    <item>
         <title>Item C</title>
         <description>This is the description for Item C</description>
         <id>1003</id>
    </item>
    <item>
         <title>Item B</title>
         <description>This is the description for Item B</description>
         <id>1002</id>
    </item>
```

I need to grab the node from SOURCE with the 'id' matching '1003' (in this example) and import it into the DESTINATION. I'm looking for insight in using importNode (or a simpleXML option) and also the xpath in only getting only the node I need.

Comment: The XPath expression would be `/items/item[id = 1003]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do that and it should work :

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/xml'); //Just to test in the browser directly and have a good format

$docSource = new DOMDocument();
$docSource->loadXML(file_get_contents('source.xml'));
$docDest = new DOMDocument();
$docDest->loadXML(file_get_contents('destination.xml'));

$xpath = new DOMXPath($docSource);

$result = $xpath->query('//item[id=1003]')->item(0); //Get directly the node you want

$result = $docDest->importNode($result, true); //Copy the node to the other document

$items = $docDest->getElementsByTagName('items')->item(0);
$items->appendChild($result); //Add the copied node to the destination document

echo $docDest->saveXML();
```

Comment: This is the route that I went first and it worked for me. The xpath works exactly right and everything is happening as it should. Huge help -- and very easy to understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To get the correct node, I think your XPath should look like this:

```
$xpath->query('/items/item/id[.="1003"]/..')
```

To import it to the other document, you'll need to create the document and call `importNode` with the second parameter set to `true`:

```
$newDom = new DOMDocument;
$newDom->load('destination.xml');

$newNode = $newDom->importNode($el, true);
$newDom->firstChild->appendChild($newNode);

file_put_contents('destination.xml', $newDom->saveXML());
```